# Why do I have to import twice in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, import

I have this module that is importing BrowserModule in the decorator and also as a JavaScript import. Why do I have to import twice in Angular 2?

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser' //HERE
import { PonyRacerAppComponent } from './app.component';
@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule], //AND HERE
    declarations: [PonyRacerAppComponent],
    bootstrap: [PonyRacerAppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {

}
```

Comment: The import statement at the top acts more like a using statement so that it brings the class into scope on the file. The imports property in the metadata actually registers external modules with your module.

Comment: Well thank you Jaime Still, thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to help. Sorry that dude closed your question. The answer on the linked question isn't very readable :/

Comment: Yeap, the linked question had his answer and maybe he thought nobody could answer better than him. Thanks again dude